# Cannot load XIB into reusable TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, xib

I created an XIB file and its controller to handle my reusable custom cells:

[image]

And set my XIB's class owner:

[image]

```
class WallTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    //Outlets
    
    func setupCell() {
        setupLabels()
    }
    
    func setupLabels() {
        self.title.text = "Sample Title"
        self.postDescriptionLabel.text = "Sample Description"
    }
}
```

I, currently have 2 storyboards, where the first one leads to the second one, using a `NavigationView`, the second one contains a `TabBarView` where the first of the items has a `TableView`.

Here, I added a `UITableViewCell` in the storyboard

[image]

The cell's class is set to:

[image]

And the controller's class is set to:

[image]

Where I register my Nib and try to use it on the `cellForRowAt` method:

```
class WallViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var messagesTable: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        loadNibForCells()
    }
    
    func loadNibForCells() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "WallTableCell", bundle: nil)
        messagesTable.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "wallCell")
    }
}

extension WallViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let wallCell = messagesTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wallCell") as? WallTableCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        wallCell.setupCell()
        
        return wallCell
    }
}
```

But still, when I run the app in the simulator, I keep getting an empty cell.

[image]

What should I do in order to display my custom XIB view inside my tableViewCell?

After following @Sh_Khan's answer and adding:

```
messagesTable.delegate = self
messagesTable.dataSource = self
```

The app crashes with an error:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "[<NSObject 0x600001628e70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key postDescriptionLabel"
```

I believe it has to do with the fact that the `TableViewCell` inside the storyboard is empty rather than containing the components of the `WallTableCell`

Comment: What is in `.setupCell()` for your `wallCell`

Comment: It's the first code in the question, it just sets up the labels' text `self.title.text = "Sample Title"` and `self.postDescriptionLabel.text = "Sample Description"` @HarryJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was missing to add my `messagesTable`'s dataSource which was what Sh_Khan recommended, the solution for my error afterwards was that my reference outlets were pointing to "File's owner" rather than my File's outlets.

So, when selecting the custom `TableViewCell` (not the prototype) should be:

[image]

For some reason, instead of being "Title Label" on the right side, it was "File's owner"

And the prototype cell shouldn't contain any class attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set dataSource and delegate if needed

```
messagesTable.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "wallCell")
messagesTable.delegate = self
messagesTable.dataSource = self
```

Comment: I added both lines as you did, but now I keep getting another error, I think it has to do with the fact that my TableViewCell inside my Storyboard is empty rather than having the components inside it. I will post the error in an edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

There is an error: `Thread 1: Exception: "[<NSObject 0x600001628e70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key postDescriptionLabel"`, so maybe you need to unbind the `postDescriptionLabel` and bind it from xib file to swift file again.